# Proxy api server through angular application

Tags: angular6

I am trying to proxy [api server](http://([https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/fundamentals/understanding-apis-and-api-proxies][1]))  through an Angular 6 application and I get the following error:

> UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY .

How to resolve this?

Comment: can you please post your code?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're trying to reverse proxy a secure connection, and all secure connection require a certificate to encrypt the connection.

You could either drop the security:

```
  "/example": {
    "target": "http://example.com"
    "secure": false
  }
```

Or generate the certificates (), and letting devServer (`ng serve`) know where they are......... which i couldn't find any documentation, about. So I suggest you do as I did and set up a reverse proxy in top of angular to manage this; i prefere nginx but you can use node's proxy-middleware.

By the way, I do think the documentation of the case is lacking, so do all of this people -> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1896

Refs
https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/10